# Using Pyspark read data from elastic search and convert into json: error while reading nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read data from elastic search using PySpark and convert it into json based on selected columns. If the json has nested objects, I am getting error as "**notification.address not found. typically this occurs with arrays which are not mapped as single value"**
Below is my ES data

```html
{
 {
  "notification": {
    "Id" : "123",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "address" : {
      "street" : "avenue",
      "zip" : "08812"
    }
  } 
 },
 {
  "notification": {
    "Id" : "897",
    "name" : "abc",
    "address" : {
      "street" : "34-ave",
      "zip" : "02324"
    }
  } 
 },
}
```

My Elastic search query looks like below

```html
df = spark.read.format(org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
     .option("es.node","")\
     .option("es.port","")\
     .option("es.nodes.wan.only", True)\
.option("es.read.field.include,"notification.Id,notification.name,notification.address.street,notification.address.zip")\
     .option("es.query","")\
     .lod("index")
```

Now my issue is while converting to json, I cannot read nested objects.Below is my code to convert dataframe

```html
df_user = df.withColumn("notification",to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
```

The above line gives me error
***notification.address not found. typically this occurs with arrays which are not mapped as single value***

Comment: In your sample json, the inner object doesn't have a key? isn't it suppose to be an array of notifications?

Comment: I got the above issue fixed by adding .option("es.read.field.array.include")